# Beta regression (proportions) with phylogenetic comparative analysis?

Tags: r, beta-distribution, beta-regression, phylogeny

Is there a package in R that allows phylogenetic comparative analysis of proportion data (i.e. a beta distribution)?

Answer (score 1):

You can do GLMMs including phylogeny as an error term in the package `brms`. See [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/brms/vignettes/brms_phylogenetics.html) for an example. The package also allows for beta distribution. The new version of `glmmTMB` also allows you to include several types of [covariance structures](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmmTMB/vignettes/covstruct.html) and includes the beta distribution.

Comment: Hi Diogo, sorry for the very slow reply. Looking at "Covariance structures with glmmTMB" it's not clear how I should incorporate the phylogenetic data. I assume I need heterogeneous unstructured covariance, but thought I would need to include a covariance matrix from the phylo/tree. I don't see how the example relates to this. Do you have any more information on how to write the correct model?

Answer (score 1):

There is an (as yet unpublished) extension to `glmmTMB` that fits phylogenetic models by creating a specially structured `Z` matrix: see [here](https://github.com/wzmli/phyloglmm), [here](https://zenodo.org/record/2639887#.YqylKzXMKto), [here](https://wzmli.github.io/talks/isec2018.pdf).

Comment: I'm trying to follow the example ("example.pdf") given in wzmli/phyloglmm-v1.0.0.zip but am getting errors. When I try to run the line "phylo_lmm_fit" it says "Error in match.fun(FUN) : object 'safeDeparse' not found". When I try to run "glmmTMB_fit" it says "Error in model.matrix(glmmTMB:::drop.special2(fixedform), fr, contrasts) : 
object 'drop.special2' not found". I've checked all listed packages are installed and up to date. Wanted to try this example as haven't been able to get my own model to work.